# Change a sql statement when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, sql, checkbox

So I tried Google before I posted this and didn't find anything that suited my needs. I was hoping you guys could help.

I have a form simple just a drop down box and a checkbox. The drop down box shows a list of names pulled from a database. The checkbox is initially unchecked. What I want to happen is that when the user clicks on the box the page will refresh and update the drop down box to include more names in the list depending up on the sql query that I have set up.

so form looks like this :

```
    <form name="search" method="post" action="myaction.php">
       <table width="100%">
          <tr>
             <td><label>Select a name to search for:</label></td>
             <td><select name='mynames'><?php 
              echo "<option value='0'>-- Select a Name --</option>";
              mysql_data_seek($request_staff, 0);
              while ($row_mynames = mysql_fetch_assoc($mynames)) {
              echo "<option value='".$row_mynames['myID']."'>".$row_mynames['firstName'] . " " . $row_mynames['lastName'] ."</option>" ; }?></select></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkActive" value="1">Include additional Names</td>                                                                                    
              <td><button id="submit" type="submit" ><span>Search</span></button></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </form>
```

I think I may need some javascript but I wasn't sure I found several things that suggested just checking when the submit button is checked, but I need it to check before the form is submitted.

the sql statement is pretty simple just

```
    $sql = "Select myID, fName, lName, extraNames from myTable $mysearch;
```

I want a where clause like this : (I know this isn't correct code but this is what I want it to do)

```
    if checkbox is checked {
       $mysearch = "";
    }else {
       $mysearch = "Where extraNames = 1";
    }
```

I have some javascript that checks a checkbox on another page, but I couldn't figure out how to change the sql query (written in php) with the javascript. Thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: You need Ajax and JS for this.

Comment: ok so I have a function for checking if the checkbox is check in a jquery function but how do I set a variable or change the sql statement from inside that function?

Answer (score 0):

`HTML`

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="myaction.php" id="myForm">
   <table width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td><label>Select a name to search for:</label></td>
         <td><select name='mynames'><?php 
          echo "<option value='0'>-- Select a Name --</option>";
          mysql_data_seek($request_staff, 0);
          while ($row_mynames = mysql_fetch_assoc($mynames)) {
          echo "<option value='".$row_mynames['myID']."'>".$row_mynames['firstName'] . " " . $row_mynames['lastName'] ."</option>" ; }?></select></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkActive" value="1" onclick="$('#myForm').submit();">Include additional Names</td>                                                                                    
          <td><button id="submit" type="submit" ><span>Search</span></button></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
```

`PHP`

```
$sql = "Select myID, fName, lName, extraNames from myTable";
if (!empty($_POST['checkActive'])) {
   $sql .= "WHERE `extraNames` = 1";
}
```

Comment: I tried the onclick you suggested and it doesn't reload the dropdown it still shows the initial values.

Comment: can you output the content from `$_POST`? (`var_export($_POST`) So you can see if `checkActive` is indeeed 1, when the checkbox is checked

Comment: ok how do I get it to show the value status? what I have tried doesn't seem to work.

Comment: var_export($_POST); die;  What does this show after you have clicked on the checkbox and checked it?

Comment: I get array ( ) before I check the box and the page stays the same when it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Since the web page is running in a browser on the client side (the HTML) and the SQL query is running on the server (the PHP), you'll need to add a parameter to the page (the HTML) that indicates if the check box was clicked. When the form is submitted to the `myaction.php` URL on the server, you can then feed the value of that parameter into the `if checkbox is checked` statement.

Comment: are you meaning in the php or in a javascript function?

Comment: I have updated my answer to clarify. In essence, cornelb has provided an example of just what I recommended.

Comment: Ok but what cornelb provided didn't work either. The page doesn't "reload" when I check the box. So the drop down will still be holding the same data it did to start with.